# Connecting Bluetooth headset to MacBook Pro, won't last more than a second

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect my bluetooth headset to a MacBook Pro (my work laptop).

(It's an Anko/Kmart neckband with earphones and mic, which is working perfectly with all other Windows/Android devices).

On my Mac, I can see the headset in System Preferences > Bluetooth.

[image: The headset in System Preferences > Bluetooth]

When I hit Connect:

1. "Not Connected" changes to "Connected", the headset appears briefly in *System Preferences > Sound*, while I hear the "connected sound" in my headset,
2. immediately followed by "disconnected sound", while the "Connected" changes back to "Not Connected", and the headset disappears from *System Preferences > Sound*

It won't stay connected for more than a second, often less than a second.
Any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT 1**

I tried clicking "Connect" like crazy and after 20+ tries it now stays connected!
[image]

But this time I can't see it in *System Preferences > Sound* at all, and therefore no sound through the headset.

**EDIT 2**

After more tries (ie. cliking like crazy), it stays connected and the device stays in *System Preferences > Sound*. Now it works perfectly!

I guess my question is now, is there any way to make this connecting process more reliable? (Or an auto-retry so I don't have to click it 100 times before it stays connected?)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure it's not connected to other devices. Then Forget the device on your Mac and re-pair. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Adam! After so many tries I finally got it working! But this happens every time I want to connect the headset. I need to try connecting like 100 times to get it to work.

Comment: @Aximili Consider accepting the answer if it answer your question. It will avoid Community user from bumping it as unanswered.